# How to sort GridFS files by date using MongoDB Java Driver?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, mongodb-java

The [GridFS API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html) doesn't seem to have a `.sort` like to the [DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) object has

Is there a way to sort by `uploadDate` (or any other GridFS metadata field)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to sort directly the fs.files as a normal collection and based on the result retrieve the files with the GridFS API.

For example:

```
var cur = db.fs.files.find({}, {"_id" : true}).sort({"uploadDate" : true})
```

Then you can use the id values to retrieve the files.